Test Explorer doesn't detect C++ Google Tests in Visual Studio 2022 when method is defined in .cpp file
I have a google test project (ProjUnitTests) that tests functions from my development project (ProjDev). The tests build successfully and can run, but Test Explorer does not discover any of my tests.
Here is the setup of my test class in ProjUnitTests:
#include "pch.h"
#include "UtilitiesBaseMath.h"

TEST(UtilitiesMathTest, AddTest) 
{
    EXPECT_EQ(UtilitiesBaseMath::addint(3, 5), 8);
}

Class under test: UtilitiesBaseMath
UtilitiesBaseMath.cpp:
#include "stdafx.h"  // Always include this first in .cpp files
#include "UtilitiesBaseMath.h"

// Method definition
int UtilitiesBaseMath::addint(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

UtilitiesBaseMath.h:
#pragma once
// Define the export/import macros 
#ifdef LP_EXPORTS
#define LP_UNIT_TEST __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LP_UNIT_TEST __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class LP_UNIT_TEST UtilitiesBaseMath 
{
public:
    static int addint(int a, int b);
};

Problem:
When I define the addint method in the .cpp file, Test Explorer cannot detect or display any tests. However, if I define the method entirely in the .h file, like this:
static int addint(int a, int b) { 
    return a + b; 
}

The tests appear correctly in Test Explorer, and they run as expected.
What I've Tried:
I've already checked similar requests:
text
This solution didn’t help as the user's issue was resolved by copying their project to a local drive from a NAS, but my project is already on a local drive.
text
This didn’t solve my issue either because I am not using CMake.
Additional Information:
My issue only occurs when the method body is moved to the .cpp file. When everything is defined in the header, it works fine and the tests show up in Test Explorer.
Remarks following your comments:

I have configured the gtest test adapter and I can run the test by clicking on the "Local Windows Debugger" button in VS2022 or by pressing the F5 key and consol shows all my tests.
UtilitiesBaseMath is compiled on ProjDev.dll and this dll is very well linked to my test project ProjUnitTests.
I use the LP_UNIT_TEST macro to be able to export the methods from my ProjDev.dll project and import them into my test project. in this case, addint, it's just an example I made to be able to share with you my problem and simplify things. There are many methods in this class that I need to test and they generate the same problem like this example.

I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Do you have the Test Adapter for Google Test set up correctly in Visual Studio 2022?  (link)

How is this all compiled together? Is UtilitiesBaseMath.cpp compiled into a dll?

Couple of things look weird. What is "LgpUtilitiesBase.h"? Why LP_UNIT_TEST macro in your production code? static int addint in the context of a free function means it has internal linkage, why would you do that, to define UtilitiesBaseMath::addint in terms of free function? Is the test binary compiled and linked successfully in both cases? If you run your binary with --gtest_list_tests arg, does it show your tests correctly? Please provide [mcve].

@Eljay, yes absolutely I have configured the gtest test adapter and I can run the test by clicking on the "Local Windows Debugger" button in VS2022 or by pressing the F5 key. But the tests do not appear in the test explorer.

@AlanBirtles Yes UtilitiesBaseMath is compiled on ProjDev.dll and this dll is very well linked to my test project ProjUnitTests.

@pptaszni thank you for your respond I will try to answer to all questions. So, sorry it's my fault, I correct the code it's UtilitiesBaseMath.h and not LgpUtilitiesBase.h. I can run the test by clicking on the "Local Windows Debugger" button in VS2022 or by pressing the F5 key and I see the status of my tests displayed in the console but not in the Test Explorer.

@pptaszni I use the LP_UNIT_TEST macro to be able to export the methods from my ProjDev.dll project and import them into my test project. in this case, addint, it's just an example I made to be able to share with you my problem and simplify things. There are many methods in this class that I need to test and they generate the same problem like this example

It could also be a bug in VS. Microsoft notoriously provides bad quality programming tools, so I wouldn't be surprised.

From doc, it seems there is 2 ways to discover tests, Real-time test discovery (looking from source), one after the build. The second/old way should find your test...

@pptaszni I run "--gtest_list_tests" and it display these: Initializing!
Running main() from D:\a_work\1\s\googletest\googletest\src\gtest_main.cc
UtilitiesMathTest.
AddTest

Super, then it sounds like your test is there. Now the question is why Test Explorer doesn't see it.
